# How to send and receive messages when IBM Websphere MQ is used

Tags: jms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using JMS to connect to IBM MQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324038/using-jms-to-connect-to-ibm-mq)

I know that JMS is a messaging standard provided by sun and IBM Websphere MQ is an implementation of JMS.

I have always used JMS and never used MQ. So i have a couple of questions.

Using JMS I will configure the connection factory and the queues in the application server and use the below code to send and receive messages. In JMS we use the javax.jms.*  package.

Code for sending message

```
Context context = new InitialContext();
QueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory =`enter code here`
(QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup("QueueConnectionFactory");
String queueName = "MyQueue";
Queue queue = (Queue) context.lookup(queueName);
queueConnection =
queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection() ;
QueueSession queueSession =
queueConnection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
QueueSender queueSender = queueSession.createSender(queue);
TextMessage message = queueSession.createTextMessage();
message.setText("This is a TextMessage");
queueSender.send(message) ;
```

Code for receiving message

```
Context context = new InitialContext(); 
QueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory =(QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup("QueueConnectionFactory"); 
String queueName = "MyQueue";
Queue queue = (Queue) context.lookup(queueName); 
QueueConnection  queueConnection =queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection() ;
QueueSession queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession (false, •*■ Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE) ;
QueueReceiver queueReceiver = queueSession.createReceiver(queue);
queueConnection.start() ;
Message message = queueReceiver.receive(1) ;
```

Please let me know how i can send the receive the messages when iam using IBM Websphere MQ. Does IBM provide any API which help in sending and receiving the messages when IBM MQ is being used?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324038/using-jms-to-connect-to-ibm-mq/3248980#3248980

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a JNDI naming service to provide your JMS objects for Websphere MQ. The Websphere MQ utility for that is JMSAdmin. If you've got Websphere Application Server, you can alternatively set up JMS resources (connection factory and queues or topics) using 'Websphere MQ messaging provider'. Note that the names defined in Websphere MQ are not the same as JNDI names: you choose whan JNDI name will refer to what Websphere MQ name when setting up these bindings.